# avoid duplicates in flash based messaging

Tags: php, class

I am using a php session-based flash messenger [available](http://mikeeverhart.net/php/session-based-flash-messages/) here. The issue is sometimes I get multiple messages of the same type when I generate errors, display messages, so on and so fourth. This is mostly due to some AJAX issues. Assuming that I wanted to only apply a fix in the display code here:

```
public function display($type = 'all', $print = true)
{
    $messages = '';
    $data = '';
    if (!isset($_SESSION['flash_messages'])) {
        return false;
    }
    // print a certain type of message?
    if (in_array($type, $this->msgTypes)) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['flash_messages'][$type] as $msg) {
            $messages .= $this->msgBefore . $msg . $this->msgAfter;
        }
        $data .= sprintf($this->msgWrapper, $this->msgClass, $this->msgClassPrepend.'-'.$type, str_replace('messages', 'autoclose',$this->msgClassPrepend.'-'.$type), $messages);
        // clear the viewed messages
        $this->clear($type);
    // print ALL queued messages
    } elseif ($type == 'all') {
        $counter = 1;
        foreach ($_SESSION['flash_messages'] as $type => $msgArray) {
            $count = $counter++;
            $messages = '';
            foreach ($msgArray as $msg) {
                $messages .= $this->msgBefore . $msg . $this->msgAfter;
            }
            $data .= sprintf($this->msgWrapper, $this->msgClass, $this->msgClassPrepend.'-'.$type, str_replace('messages', 'autoclose', $this->msgClassPrepend.'-'.$type), $messages);
        }
        // clear ALL of the messages
        $this->clear();
        // invalid message type?
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    // print everything to the screen or return the data
    if ($print) {
        echo $data;
    } else {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

How would I make it so that duplicate messages are detected on a 1 for 1 basis. So if the message is "Hello" and "Hello" and "Hello." I can remove one of the first two, and keep the later as it is a different message so to speak. All the workarounds I can think of would be overly complex, and I was wondering if anyone could think of a simple solution.

Additional info: `display` is encased in `class Messages` and a new message is created with

```
$msg = new Messages();
$msg->add('e', 'Some error here.');
```

Comment: Is the ajax doing more than one request? The point is if ajax do more than one request then you can control it in the php, if not you will need to handle it in the JavaScript... Do you understand?

Comment: its not ajax, just session based... so when the page with display loads after a redirect from another page that added a message to the session, then that message is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply run the message array through [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-unique.php) before the `$messages` string is built. For example, these two additions to the `display` method should do the trick...

```
if (in_array($type, $this->msgTypes)) {
    $filtered = array_unique($_SESSION['flash_messages'][$type]);
    foreach ($filtered as $msg) {
```

and...

```
foreach ($_SESSION['flash_messages'] as $type => $msgArray) {
    $count = $counter++;
    $messages = '';
    $filtered = array_unique($msgArray);
    foreach ($filtered as $msg) {
```

Alternatively, you could override the [`add`](https://github.com/plasticbrain/PHP-Flash-Messages/blob/master/class.messages.php#L98) method with a *unique* check. For example

```
public function add($type, $message, $redirect_to = null, $ignoreDuplicates = true) {
    // snip...

    // wrap the array push in this check
    if (!($ignoreDuplicates && in_array($message, $_SESSION['flash_messages'][$type]))) {
        $_SESSION['flash_messages'][$type][] = $message; // this is the existing code
    }

    // snip...
}
```

Comment: First method worked, the add method did not. Either way! Thanks for the tremendous help, very informative.

Comment: @Alex Hmm, in my tests, the `add` method check works fine. You need to wrap that `if` block around the existing code that adds messages to the stack

Comment: maybe just add the full add code here so i can see if/what i was doing wrong ;)